# What's the difference between an cabin and a stable?

Tags: mmo-incremental

I can upgrade my hut to either a cabin or a stable. What is the difference? Is there any way to see what the actual stat increases/new options will be from new buildings in advance of building them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Cabin increases your storage capacity by 10,000 and gives you the scheduling option to sleep in the cabin to gain 60 zen.

A Stable loses all storage capacity, but gives you the ability to schedule a horse drawn carriage at the cost of 20 energy and 10 food to gain 30 wood.